# Como mostra a posição da linha e coluna de uma matriz em C e soma a linha e a coluna

Tags: c, matriz, array-multidimensional

Boa tarde Galera!!!!
Sei que a pergunta parece boba, mais estou começando agora em programação precisava fazer um programa em C com uma **MATRIZ[4][4]** conforme descrito aqui em baixo. Já faz uns dias que estou tentando fazer, mais sem sucesso.
O usuário não irá entrar com nenhum dado é só pra mostrar os dados igual descritos a baixo nem mais nem menos.

Crie um PROGRAMA em C que apresente a seguinte saída:

Linha: 0 coluna: 1 valor: 1
  Linha: 1 coluna: 1 valor: 2
  Linha: 2 coluna: 1 valor: 3
  Linha: 3 coluna: 1 valor: 4
  Linha: 4 coluna: 1 valor: 5

Esse aqui é o código que fiz.
O Programa roda sem erros, mais mais não imprime os valores do exemplo acima, imprime os números errados, não mostra os valores da linha e nem da coluna.

Desde já agradeço. :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int l, c, cont, matriz[4][4];
    char valor = 'x';
    cont = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            matriz[l][c] = cont + 1;
        }
    }

    for (l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            printf("Linha: %d   Coluna: %d  Valor: %s", matriz[l][c], valor);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}`
```

Comment: Se entendi corretamente seu problema troque: `printf("Linha: %d   Coluna: %d  Valor: %s", matriz[l][c], valor);` por: `printf("Linha: %d   Coluna: %d  Valor: %d", l, c, matriz[l][c]);`.

Comment: Pra que criar a matriz 4x4 se você só usa até a segunda coluna? Além disso, não faz sentido vc imprimir a letra "x" várias vezes, eu acho que o x deveria ser trocado pelo respectivo valor daquela linha e coluna, não? (Conforme sugeriu o comentário acima) - Se fosse pra imprimir a letra "x" várias vezes, nem precisaria dessa matriz, era só fazer um loop

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, meu printf estava errado. Pensando aqui você tem razão em exibir varias vezes o X.

Comment: Reverti a edição porque ela mudava a pergunta, e isso é ruim porque invalida as respostas que já foram dadas. Se quer perguntar outra coisa (mesmo que esteja relacionada), então [faça outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Entendi,fiz meu cadastro hoje e foi minha primeira pergunta aqui. Mais beleza, vou me atentar a isso a próxima vez. Vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui somar aqui. Estava colocando a variável **valor** *"que é a responsável por somar a linha e coluna"*  no lugar errado. Segue o código que deu certo a soma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int l, c, cont, matriz[4][4];
    int valor;
    cont = 0;
    valor = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            matriz[l][c] = cont + 1;

        }
    }

    for (l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            valor = valor + matriz[l][c];
            printf("Linha: %d   Coluna: %d  Valor: %d", l, c, valor);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}`
```

Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram. São erros bobos, mais que passam despercebidos pra que ta começando agora.